# Javascript : Creating Objects using Literals

Tags: javascript

I have been learning beginner js and have come across creating objects using literals. The code is as follows:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr8nbjvw/1/)

```
<script>

    var phone= {
    name : "iPhone",
    brand : "Apple",
    version : "5",
    edition : function(){
        alert("The cellphone's Version  is iPhone" + this.version);
    };

    function demo(){
         console.log(phone.brand); 
         console.log(phone.version); 
         console.log(phone.name); 
    }

</script>
<p>Click the button below</p>
<button onclick="demo();">JS Object Literals</button>
```

However, whenever the button is clicked, `demo()` function doesn't show up anything.

Please anyone help me to point out the error.

Comment: And is there a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up curly braces in your js + in your html, you have to call `phone.demo()`

In jsfiddle, if you want to access phone from the html, don't put `var` before (it makes it private to a specific js closure and not accessible to the global space)

html

```
<button onclick="phone.demo();">JS Object Literals</button>
```

js

```
phone= {
    name : "iPhone",
    brand : "Apple",
    version : "5",
    edition : function(){
        alert("The cellphone's Version  is iPhone" + this.version);
    },
    demo: function(){
        console.log(phone.brand); 
        console.log(phone.version); 
        console.log(phone.name); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a syntax error.

You are missing the final `}` and the `;` should not be there after the function

```
var phone= {
    name : "iPhone",
    brand : "Apple",
    version : "5",
    edition : function(){
        alert("The cellphone's Version  is iPhone" + this.version);
    }
};
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cr8nbjvw/2/

---

On the jsfiddle when calling functions directly from DOM elements attributes you need to select on the dropdown (top/left) the **`No wrap - in <head>`** option, so that your methods are global.

Comment: Gaby, didn't know the `No wrap - in <head>` trick on jsfiddle ;-)